# Getting SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'login' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null error

Tags: android, magento, soap

I want to call Magento Soap v2 API methods in android code. For this i need session_id according to this http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.tree.html

I have tried this code to get session_id, but getting error 'Procedure 'login' not present'. I am new to use Soap v2 API.

Request :

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
private static final String Method_Name="login";
private static final String URL ="http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="urn:Magento/login";

        try {

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopes = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelopes.dotNet = false;
        envelopes.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        envelopes.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, Method_Name);
        request.addProperty("username", "xxxxxx");
        request.addProperty("apiKey", "xxxxxxx");
        envelopes.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;
        httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelopes);
        Object result = envelopes.getResponse();
        Log.d("sessionId", result.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Response :

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'login' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Comment: Do you have a user created in Magento admin to access SOAP requests?

Comment: yes, i have created user in Magento and i am using username and api_key in soap request which i have set for that user.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050778/soapfault-faultcode-soap-env-exception-in-android

Comment: I have referred this link but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

you please try this now .

```
http://your machine IP address /magento/index.php/api/soap
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap
```